# loadComplete and gridComplete of jqgrid are not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am new to javascript and jqgrid. I know that similar questions have already been asked. But none of them worked for me. So, I am posting my question. I am rendering jqgrid with the help of following code.

```
$("#allpatcentics").jqGrid({
                    data: lsJQGridMyDashbrdData,
                    datatype: "local",
                    loadonce: true,
                    autowidth: true,
                    height: apppatienttable,
                    width: null,
                    rowNum: 50,
                    rownumbers: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    cmTemplate: {
                            title: false
                    },
                    sortname: 'id',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    shrinkToFit: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    colNames: lsJQGridMyDashbrdColNames,
                    colModel: lsJQGridMyDashbrdColModel,
                    //multiselect: true,
                    loadComplete: function () {
                            $('.lbluetd').closest('tr').addClass('lbluetr');
                            $('.lbluetd').closest('td').attr({
                                    'colspan': '12'
                            }).nextAll().remove();

                            $('.blank-row').closest('tr').css({
                                    'height': '10px'
                            });
                            $('.blank-row').closest('tr').find('td').remove();

                    },
                    gridComplete : function()
                    {
                        $scope.$compile(jQuery('#allpatcentics').contents())($scope);
                    }
            });
```

Jqgrid is rendering properly, but gridComplete and loadComplete callbacks are not fired. I have confirmed this by putting breakpoint in those callbacks in inspect element of chrome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any fiddle? have you tried to put an alert inside those functions? so when they fired, the alert will show up

Comment: can you put an alert inside loadComplete & gridComplete and see if it is alerting?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Could you provide test data for `lsJQGridMyDashbrdData` to reproduce the problem? The best would be to create JSFiddle demo. I develop free jqGrid fork and recommend you to try to change URLs to jqGrid file to URLs to free jqGrid 4.13.2 (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) at least for one test.

Comment: The `colModel` and `colNames` are required too. The value `height: apppatienttable` is unclear. I recommend to use `height: "auto"`. The code from `loadComplete` is not optimal and very slow. One should use `rowattr` instead.

Comment: Actually, I can't post code on jsfiddle. Actually, this code is a part of big and complex js file. Is there any other alternative, through which I can give code to you all.

Comment: Sorry, but one can't find the bug in the problem with the following code: `someFunc(somePaaram);`. One have to know more details. The `loadComplete` and `gridComplete` will be called at the end of processing of the page of data from `lsJQGridMyDashbrdData`. The data have to be read, sorted and formatted based on `colModel: lsJQGridMyDashbrdColModel`. Probably you get exception on the stage. Moreover the code pf jqGrid, which process the data is **very different** in different jqGrid versions and in different forks of jqGrid. One can't help you if you don't post more details.